# azure cloud costs

Tags: azure

I was looking for any basic costs for a simple site.
this site accepts an input from the customer. This field is a product number much like a ISBN or UCC.

We have a database which has this number along with name and price. we have a program in C# which displays the price and name.

my question is, what is the cost to have this database in the Azure cloud, and the small app I described. there would also be a user table and some smaller tables. how does the costing work regarding the database tables, and app code?

There is only one lookup per data entry, straight forward, enter the code, if it exists, display the price and name.

I dont know if this is unclear or ambiguous question i apologize if it is, but am trying to determine costs of using the ac.

Answer (score 2):

You should look at the [calculator](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?scenario=web).

- 100MB SQL Database: **$5.00/mo** (this can be much cheaper if you convert it to table storage).
- Web Site

  - Free (you cannot use a custom DNS): **$0.00**
  - Shared (allows you to use custom DNS): **$9.36/mo**
- Egress Bandwidth (10GB/mo to USA/EU): **$0.60/mo**